# Is Neo4j capable to store data in HDFS?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

#### Q1: Is it possible to use HDFS as a storage backend for Neo4j?

My raw data is Terabyte large(2TB to 3TB, still under processing hence unable to tell exactly how much vertices and edges), so naturally I'm concerned if Neo4j is still suitable under the situation. our current cluster has 64-cores CPU, 128G RAM per node, whereas the data can't fit in local HDD, unless the graph can be stored in HDFS.

#### Q2: Will Neo4j benifit performance from HA Cluster mode?

Does HA Cluster only distribute replica on each cluster node, or Neo4j runs queries in parallel to gain high-performance? If latter, does each node holds a copy of the whole graph(let's assume the entire graph is really big) to reduce network IO overhead?

Thanks in advance!

BR,
Todd Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It should be possible, but you need to hdfs mount as regular hdd.

But from my point of view it doesn't make sense, because then I/O operation will be very slow. If you compare it to SSD.

2) It increases performance, because you can use multiple machines (slaves) for read operations.
- http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha-how.html

Comment: Is it possible to mount a certain directory of HDFS as HDD?

Comment: @ToddLeo yes, it's possible - https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/MountableHDFS

But there is no advantage to use HDFS.

Comment: Hi Mic, I'm still obsessed in this, after nearly a whole year. You said

Comment: Hi Mic, I'm still obsessed in this, after nearly a whole year. You said I/O operation will be very slow, comparing to SSD. How does it compares to HDD? Does it loss performance when storing the whole data directory to HDFS (point `data/` directory to the same HDFS URI on all machines in cluster)